# How to fix an error while importing functions in python?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-module

I am learning how to import functions from other files, and I am facing an error where python is listing the folder the code is in as a module that can't be found.

Folder named: My_Code
Two Files: Scratch_1, Scratch_2

Scratch_1:

```
def function(sample):
    return sample
```

Scratch_2:

```
import My_Code.Scratch_1 as s1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = 5
    print(s4.function(test))
```

Returns:

```
import My_Code.Scratch as function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'My_Code'
```

I have used:

```
from Scratch_1 import function
```

Now I am running into files where I have so many functions that the top of my code has become clustered. Anything helps thank you

Comment: Python won't import files that aren't named *.py.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type it here, they are named Scratch_1.py and Scratch_2.py

Comment: `Scratch_2` is already inside the `My_Code` folder.  So `import My_Code.Scratch_1 as s1` would expect there to be _another_ subdirectory named `My_Code`.

Comment: OHH okay, so I would effectively have to separate the directories and treat it as like numpy or matplotlib , etc